# Adding bootstrap-select to Datatables's length-menu

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-select

people!

I need help. I'm trying to change the css of the datatables dropdown "length-menu" but it disappears when I add the "selectpicker" class.

When the grid is not looking for ajax data, it works by changing the style, but when I apply it to the grid that is searching for the data via ajax or the dropdown some.

Where am I going wrong?

```
[CODE]
grid = $('#grid').DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500]],
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    data: $.parseJSON(response.d),
    columns: [
        { title: "Id" },
        { title: "Nome" }
    ],
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

        $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "type": "GET",
            "url": sSource,
            "data": aoData,
            "success":
                        function (msg) {
                            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                            fnCallback(json);
                            $("#grid").show();
                        }
        });

    },
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow) {

        $(nRow).on('click', function () {

            grid.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0),
                aData = grid.row(row).data();

        });
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "Id", "sClass": "pri tableDataCenter", "sWidth": "25px" },//0
        { "sTitle": "Nome", "sClass": "pri" }//1
    ],
    "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
        $('div.dataTables_length select').addClass('selectpicker');
        $('div.dataTables_length select').attr('data-width', '70px').attr('data-margin', '0 5px');
        $('div.dataTables_filter').addClass('form-group').addClass('label-floating');
    },
    "order": [[1, "asc"]],
    "oLanguage": {
        "oPaginate": {
            "sNext": "Próxima",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior",
            "sFirst": "Primeira página",
            "sLast": "Última página"
        },
        "sEmptyTable": "",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Nenhum Registro Encontrado...",
        "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ de registros.",
        "sInfoFiltered": " - pesquisado em _MAX_ registros.",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Por favor Agurde...",
        "sZeroRecords": "Não há registros a serem exibidos.",
        "sProcessing": "Aguarde Processando..."
    },
});
```

Comment: This looks as though you'll need to download the bootstrap DataTable file and edit it to add the class via that, you might need to edit it. Otherwise, add the class after each draw of the table on the draw callback?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "drawCallback": function(){
        var length_select = $("#example_length");
        var select = $("#example_length").find("select").clone();
        select.addClass("selectpicker");
        length_select.empty().append(select);
        select.selectpicker();
    },
    "columns": [{
            "visible": false
        },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
});
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/LmbL7bws/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Worked perfectly.
I was able to adjust as I needed.

Comment: Glad to help :-)